# Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at final_lab.sv(46) near text "default"; expecting "end"

Tags: verilog

hello I am getting the following error in verilog and I don't know why can't seem to figure it out. please help

> Error : Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at final_lab.sv(46)
>   near text "default";  expecting "end"

code

```
module final_lab (CLOCK_50,  SW, LEDR, KEY, HEX5, HEX4, HEX3, HEX2, HEX1,HEX0); 
    input logic CLOCK_50; 
    input logic [6:1] SW; 
    input logic [3:0] KEY;

    output logic [9:0] LEDR; 
    output logic [6:0] HEX5, HEX4, HEX3, HEX2, HEX1, HEX0;

    logic [6:1] whatWeHave;
    logic reset;
    logic keyOne , keyThree;  


    assign whatWeHave = 6'b000000;

    always_comb 
        begin
        if (whatWeHave[6:1] == SW[6:1])
            begin
            keyThree = 0;
            keyOne = 0;
            whatWeHave = whatWeHave;
            end

        else if (whatWeHave[6:1] < SW[6:1])
            begin
            whatWeHave = whatWeHave+1;
            keyThree = 1;
            keyOne = 0;
            end

        else if (whatWeHave[6:1] > SW[6:1])
            begin
            whatWeHave = whatWeHave-1;
            keyOne = 1;
            keyThree = 0;
            end

        else
            begin
            whatWeHave = whatWeHave;
            keyOne = 0;
            keyThree = 0; 
            end 

        default
            begin 
            whatWeHave = 6'bxxxxxx;
            keyOne = 1'bx;
            keyThree = 1'bx;
            end
        end


    normalLight one (.clk(CLOCK_50), .reset(SW[9]), .L(keyThree), .R(keyZero), .NL(LEDR[2]), .NR(1'b0), .lightOn(LEDR[1]));

    normalLight two (.clk(CLOCK_50), .reset(SW[9]), .L(keyThree), .R(keyZero), .NL(LEDR[3]), .NR(LEDR[1]), .lightOn(LEDR[2]));

    normalLight three (.clk(CLOCK_50), .reset(SW[9]), .L(keyThree), .R(keyZero), .NL(LEDR[4]), .NR(LEDR[2]), .lightOn(LEDR[3]));

    normalLight four (.clk(CLOCK_50), .reset(SW[9]), .L(keyThree), .R(keyZero), .NL(LEDR[5]), .NR(LEDR[3]), .lightOn(LEDR[4]));

    normalLightLight five (.clk(CLOCK_50), .reset(SW[9]), .L(keyThree), .R(keyZero), .NL(LEDR[6]), .NR(LEDR[4]), .lightOn(LEDR[5]));

    normalLight six (.clk(CLOCK_50), .reset(SW[9]), .L(keyThree), .R(keyZero), .NL(1'b0), .NR(LEDR[5]), .lightOn(LEDR[6]));
endmodule
```

Comment: Try to use consistent indentation with your begin/end blocks as it can help to discover these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1):

The place where **default** is used in your logic is inappropriate. The **default** keyword is used normally along with **case** statements and not with the **if-else** conditions.

In a nested if-else, the final else (without a condition) will be executed similar to default. Looks like you are trying to have two default conditions. Try to rework your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Same as the two previous answers, **default** does not exists in **if-else** statement.
If you think about it, you have the **else** statement just before the **default** statement which will cover all the cases not previously covered, then do the job of a **default** in a **case** statement.

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong syntax. basically we use **default** as last part of **case** statement. you cannot use **default** with **if-else** statement.
just delete **default** keyword and use another **if-else** statement. ***OR*** instead of all  **if-else** statements; you can use **case** statement with **default** keyword in the last part.